# UIRefreshControl - beginRefreshing not working when UITableViewController is inside UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I've setup a UIRefreshControl in my UITableViewController (which is inside a UINavigationController) and it works as expected (i.e. pull down fires the correct event). However, if I programmatically invoke the `beginRefreshing` instance method on the refresh control like:

```
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
```

Nothing happens. It should animate down and show the spinner. The `endRefreshing` method works properly when I call that after the refresh.

I whipped up a basic prototype project with this behavior and it works properly when my UITableViewController is added directly to application delegate's root view controller, e.g:

```
self.viewController = tableViewController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

But if I add the `tableViewController` to a UINavigationController first, then add the navigation controller as the `rootViewController`, the `beginRefreshing` method no longer works. E.g.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
self.viewController = navController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

My feeling is this has something to do with the nested view hierarchies within the navigation controller not playing nice with the refresher control - any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 209, accepted):

It seems that if you start refreshing programmatically, you have to scroll the table view yourself, say, by changing contentoffset

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

I would guess the reason for this is that it could be undesirable to scroll to the refresh control when user is in the middle/bottom of the table view?

Swift 2.2 version by @muhasturk

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -refreshControl.frame.size.height), animated: true)
```

In a nutshell, to keep this portable add this extension

**UIRefreshControl+ProgramaticallyBeginRefresh.swift**

```
extension UIRefreshControl {
    func programaticallyBeginRefreshing(in tableView: UITableView) {
        beginRefreshing()
        let offsetPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: -frame.size.height)
        tableView.setContentOffset(offsetPoint, animated: true)        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that achieved the effect I was after! I had to set the content offset back to 0, 0 once refreshing was finished also.

Comment: That's strange, in my tests, endRefreshing adjusts offset as needed

Comment: It did sometimes, and not others. Could be related to the UINavigationController issue? Not sure :S

Comment: BTW, if you're using auto layout, you can replace the line in the answer with this:     [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.topLayoutGuide.length) animated:YES];

Comment: @EricBaker I believe that won't do. Not all UITableViewControllers show navigation bars. This would lead to a topLayoutGuide of length 20 and an offset too small.

Comment: @EricBaker you can use: [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.topLayoutGuide.length -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

Comment: I had to call beginRefreshing() in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad, otherwise only the title was visible, not the spinning animation.

Comment: This should fix the problem

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];           
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
       });
    }

Comment: Just a general opinion... This needs to be radar'ed if it hasn't been fixed in 11. This seems like a oversight.

Comment: Change the beginRefreshing() to the last line to fix problem with tintColor not respected on first show: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383030/860488

Answer (score 82):

UITableViewController has *automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets* property after iOS 7. The table view may already have contentOffset, usually (0, -64).

So the right way to show refreshControl after programmingly begin refreshing is adding refreshControl's height to existing contentOffset.

```
 [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
 [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y-self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

Comment: hi,Thank you a lot,I am also curious about the magic point (0, -64) I met when debugging.

Comment: @inix 20 for status bar height + 44 for navigation bar height

Comment: Instead of `-64` is better to use `-self.topLayoutGuide.length`

Answer (score 36):

Here's a Swift extension using the strategies described above.

```
extension UIRefreshControl {
    func beginRefreshingManually() {
        if let scrollView = superview as? UIScrollView {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y - frame.height), animated: true)
        }
        beginRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for UITableView.

Comment: I would recommend putting `sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)` at the end of this function, otherwise the actual refresh logic logic will not be run.

Comment: This is by far the most elegant way to do it.  Including Colin Basnett's comment for better functionality. it can be used across the whole project by defining it once!

Comment: @ColinBasnett : Adding that code (which is now sendActions(for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)), results in an infinite loop...

Answer (score 15):

None of the other answers worked for me. They would cause the spinner to show and spin, but the refresh action itself would never happen. This works:

```
id target = self;
SEL selector = @selector(example);
// Assuming at some point prior to triggering the refresh, you call the following line:
[self.refreshControl addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// This line makes the spinner start spinning
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
// This line makes the spinner visible by pushing the table view/collection view down
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -1.0f * self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
// This line is what actually triggers the refresh action/selector
[self.refreshControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Note, this example uses a table view, but it could just as well have been a collection view.

Comment: This did solve my problem. But now I'm using `SVPullToRefresh`, how to pull it down programmatically?

Comment: @Gank I've never used SVPullToRefresh. Have you tried reading their docs? It seems quite obvious based on the docs that it can be pulled down programmatically:

"If you’d like to programmatically trigger the refresh (for instance in viewDidAppear:), you can do so with:

`[tableView triggerPullToRefresh];`" 

See: https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

Comment: Perfect! It was acting strange for me with the animation though, so I simply replaced it with `scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0,
                                         y: scrollView.contentOffset.y - frame.height)`

Answer (score 13):

The already mentioned approach:

```
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
 [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y-self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

would make the spinner visible. But it wouldn't animate. The one thing I changed is the order of these two methods and everything worked:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y-self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
```

Answer (score 12):

## For Swift 4/4.1

A mix of existing answer do the job for me:

```
refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentOffset.y - (refreshControl.frame.size.height)), animated: true)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

See also this question

[UIRefreshControl not showing spiny when calling beginRefreshing and contentOffset is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120797/uirefreshcontrol-not-showing-spiny-when-calling-beginrefreshing-and-contentoffse)

It looks like a bug to me, because it only occures when the contentOffset property of the tableView is 0

I fixed that with the following code (method for the UITableViewController) :

```
- (void)beginRefreshingTableView {

    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y == 0) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^(void){

            self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        }];

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not true, I have two different UIViewControllers both of which have a contentOffset of 0 upon viewDidLoad and one of them correctly pulls down the refreshControl upon calling [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing] and the other does not :/

Comment: Documentation doesn't say anything about displaying the control on `beginRefreshing`, only that its state changes. As I see it, it is to prevent to initiate the refresh action twice, so that might a programmatically called refresh would still be running, a user initiated action won't start another.

Comment: I have noted issues with using the setContentOffset:animated method, so this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Here is **Swift 3 and later** extension that shows spinner as well as animate it.

```
import UIKit
extension UIRefreshControl {

func beginRefreshingWithAnimation() {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) {

        if let scrollView = self.superview as? UIScrollView {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y - self.frame.height), animated: true)
          }
        self.beginRefreshing()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Of all the answers above, this was the only one I could get working on iOS 11.1 / xcode 9.1

Comment: The `asyncAfter` is actually what makes the spinner animation work (iOS 12.3 / Xcode 10.2)

Answer (score 5):

It's works perfect to me:

Swift 3:

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -self.refreshControl!.frame.size.height - self.topLayoutGuide.length), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 5, for me the only thing missing was to call `refreshControl.sendActions(.valueChanged)`. I made an extension to make it more cleaner.

```
extension UIRefreshControl {

    func beginRefreshingManually() {
        if let scrollView = superview as? UIScrollView {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y - frame.height), animated: false)
        }
        beginRefreshing()
        sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
    }

}
```

Comment: calling send actions method is the only way it's working for me!

Comment: triggers infinity loop

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Dymitry Shevchenko solution.

I found nice workaround to this issue. You can create extension to `UIRefreshControl` that overwrites method:

```
// Adds code forgotten by Apple, that changes content offset of parent scroll view (table view).
- (void)beginRefreshing
{
    [super beginRefreshing];

    if ([self.superview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        UIScrollView *view = (UIScrollView *)self.superview;
        [view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, view.contentOffset.y - self.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

You can use new class by setting custom class in *Identity Inspector* for refresh control in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4):

Fort Swift 2.2+

```
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -refreshControl.frame.size.height), animated: true)
```

Comment: I've merged this with the accepted answer as it's just an update.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Rxswift for swift 3.1, can use below:

```
func manualRefresh() {
    if let refreshControl = self.tableView.refreshControl {
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -refreshControl.height), animated: true)
        self.tableView.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
        self.tableView.refreshControl?.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
    }
}
```

**This work for swift 3.1, iOS 10.**

Comment: Its the `sendActions` to trigger `rx` that makes this answer related to `RxSwift` incase anyone is wondering at first look

Comment: I had to use the refreshControl instance from the tableViewController, not the tableView. Also, that setContentOffset didn't work for me targeting iOS10. This one works however:  `self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:self.tableView.contentOffset.y - (refreshControl.frame.size.height)), animated: true)`

Answer (score 2):

**tested on Swift 5**

use this in `viewDidLoad()`

```
fileprivate func showRefreshLoader() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) {
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentOffset.y - (self.refreshControl.frame.size.height)), animated: true)
        self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing() 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the same technique for show user "data is update" visual sign. A result user bring app from background and feeds/lists will be update with UI like users pull tables to refresh himself. My version contain 3 things

1) Who send "wake up"

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationHaveToResetAllPages object:nil];
}
```

2) Observer in UIViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(forceUpdateData) name:kNotificationHaveToWakeUp:nil];
}
```

3)The protocol

```
#pragma mark - ForcedDataUpdateProtocol

- (void)forceUpdateData {
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

    if (self.refreshControl) {
        [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
        [self.refreshControl performSelector:@selector(endRefreshing) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }
}
```

[image: result]