# How to make my RefreshControl appear during ViewDidAppear

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uirefreshcontrol

## I've answered this question myself - just leaving it here now for people with the same issue.

My code is fairly simple - A custom table with a datasource to provide data asynchronously from a web service.

In order to get the nicest user experience I would like to have the `UIRefreshControl` animate the process of loading whenever this controller appears, instead of just when the list has been pulled down.

Unfortunately the `UIRefreshControl` does not appear at all if I call my method  during `ViewDidAppear`.

I've tried suggestions from answers these questions, but none of them seemed to work for me:

```
public partial class ControlCenterSelectionController : UITableViewController
{
    public ControlCenterSelectionController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        TableView.RefreshControl = new UIRefreshControl();
        TableView.RefreshControl.ValueChanged += RefreshControlOnValueChanged;
    }

    private async void RefreshControlOnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        await UpdateDataSourceAsync();
    }

    public override async void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        TableView.SetContentOffset(new CGPoint(0, -TableView.RefreshControl.Frame.Size.Height), true);
        await UpdateDataSourceAsync();
    }

    private async Task UpdateDataSourceAsync()
    {
        TableView.RefreshControl.BeginRefreshing();
        var ccClient = DI.Instance.Get<IControlCenterRestClient>();
        var controlCenters = await ccClient.GetAllAsync();
        var source = new GenericViewSource<ControlCenter>(controlCenters, item => item.Name, ControlCenterSelected);
        TableView.Source = source;
        TableView.RefreshControl.EndRefreshing();
    }

    private void ControlCenterSelected(ControlCenter controlCenter)
    {
        var controller = this.InstantiateController(Constants.ViewControllerIds.ControlCenter) as ControlCenterController;
        controller.ControlCenter = controlCenter;
        this.NavigateTo(controller);
    }
}
```

- [UITableView UIRefreshControl Does Not Show Its View The First Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193010/uitableview-uirefreshcontrol-does-not-show-its-view-the-first-time)
- [UIRefreshControl on viewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930730/uirefreshcontrol-on-viewdidload)
- [UIRefreshControl - beginRefreshing not working when UITableViewController is inside UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718850/uirefreshcontrol-beginrefreshing-not-working-when-uitableviewcontroller-is-ins)

All I currently get is a screen which looks empty, loads data without indication and then updates the screen once it's done.

Can someone spot an error? I can't really find one, since this code is rather simple.

Answer (score 1):

The desperation of posting it on SO + desperate coding attempts were key:

```
    public override async void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        TableView.SetContentOffset(new CGPoint(0, -(TableView.RefreshControl.Frame.Size.Height + 20)), true);
        TableView.RefreshControl.BeginRefreshing();
        await UpdateDataSourceAsync();
    }

    private async Task UpdateDataSourceAsync()
    {
        var ccClient = DI.Instance.Get<IControlCenterRestClient>();
        var controlCenters = await ccClient.GetAllAsync();
        var source = new GenericViewSource<ControlCenter>(controlCenters, item => item.Name, ControlCenterSelected);
        TableView.Source = source;
        TableView.RefreshControl.EndRefreshing();
    }
```

This change in particular made the difference:

```
-(TableView.RefreshControl.Frame.Size.Height + 20)
```

Turns out that, while in the other questions the issue was fixed by simply applying a scroll based on RefreshControl would fire the animation, in my case I had to add some extra y delta to make the animation fire.

## Correction

this extra offset seems to be required only if extended edges is set to extend under top bars.