# manually start refreshing UIRefreshControl on swift 3.0 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift3, uirefreshcontrol

for some time I was using code like

```
extension UIRefreshControl {
    func beginRefreshingManually() {
      if let scrollView = superview as? UIScrollView {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y - frame.height), animated: false)
      }
      beginRefreshing()
}}
```

To start manually refreshing (show spinning circle) in viewDidLoad of UIViewControllers and it works like a charm.

After migrating to swift 3.0 and iOS 10 it suddenly stops. Moreover, I tried to move invocation into viewDidAppear, and for my frustration, on some controllers it works, and on some not (If there is any pattern, I was unable to find it)

any solutions ?

cheers
Wojtek

Comment: check the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550021/uirefreshcontrol-not-refreshing-when-triggered-programmatically it works for iOS 10, swift 3

Answer (score 1):

There is a change in UIRefreshControl for iOS 10. You have been adding refresh control like this: `scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)`. Now, ScrollView, CollectionView and TableView have `refreshControl` property, so this is a code now: `scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl`

Comment: tableView had a refreshControl property before, so it is not the issue