# UIRefreshcontrol - UItableview header view is stuck and refreshview is not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UIRefreshControl` added on my `UITableView`. It works fine when screen is loading for the first time. From the second time onwards, whenever I am calling `beginRefreshing` in `viewWillAppear` then the table view header gets stuck and also the refresh control is not showing.
[image]

What could be the issue?

```
    override func ViewDidLoad(){

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlacesViewController.pullToRefresh), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 110, right: 0)

        FetchExtPlaceList([:],inBackground:inBackground)
```

}

```
func FetchExtPlaceList(pramrDisc:parameter,inBackground:Bool){

    if !inBackground{
        ActivityManager.ManageActivityView(self, action: .ActionAdd)
    }else if pageNumber == 1 {
        self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()

    }


    WSRequest.SendRequest(WSMethod.POST, pramrDisc: pramrDisc, paramsString: nil, operation: WSOperation.FetchExtPlaceList, completionHandler: { response in

        if !inBackground{
            ActivityManager.ManageActivityView(self, action: .ActionRemove)
        }

        if let errorTitle = response.errorTitle {

            if let errorDescription = response.errorDescription {
                UIAlertController.ShowAlert(errorTitle, message: errorDescription)
            }

        }else if let wsError = response.wsError {

            if let infoMessage = wsError.infoMessage {
                UIAlertController.ShowAlert("", message: infoMessage)
            }else if let errorMessage = wsError.errorMessage {
                UIAlertController.ShowAlert("", message: errorMessage)
            }else if let error = wsError.error {
                UIAlertController.ShowAlert("", message: error.description)
            }

        }else{

            if let places = response.parsedObject as? [Place]{

                if self.pageNumber == 1 {
                    self.places.removeAll()
                }

                self.places.appendContentsOf(places)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }

        if self.refreshControl.refreshing{
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: Please check i have updated question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. i was programatically calling trying to begin refreshing but i found on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718850/uirefreshcontrol-beginrefreshing-not-working-when-uitableviewcontroller-is-ins) that i have to croll the table view by changing contentoffset.