# RxSwift not show refreshControl when action is executing

Tags: swift, action, rx-swift, uirefreshcontrol

on my project I use RxSwift and Action to handle refresh indicator, but I got issues when run this code. Refresh control not showing, when I debug subscribe work properly but not showing refreshControl. It will be different when I set `self.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()` on outside `if (executing == true) {` block

```
self.viewModel.transactionHistoryNetworkRequestAction?.executing
        .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { (executing) in
            if (executing == true) {
                self.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
            } else {
                self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            }
        })
        .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to showing `UIRefreshControll` programically, as answered in: [UIRefreshControl - beginRefreshing not working when UITableViewController is inside UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718850/uirefreshcontrol-beginrefreshing-not-working-when-uitableviewcontroller-is-ins)

I reproduced your issue (refresh controls not showing) and after applying this solution to code below everything is now working.

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let testObservable = PublishSubject<Bool>()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Observable.just(true).delay(2, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).subscribe(testObservable).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        tableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        testObservable.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance).subscribe(onNext: { (executing) in
            print("Executing: \(executing)")
            self.tableView.refreshControl!.beginRefreshing()
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -self.tableView.refreshControl!.frame.size.height), animated: true)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```